# Clipping points by a polygon attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, clip

I am trying to clip a point layer with a polygon layer. My polygon layer has multiple polygons (e.g. country with different states). I am wanting to clip the point layer based on the different states contained in my country polygon layer. I realised I could do it manually by *selecting* the state and then running the **CLIP** tool from under *Vector* and then checking the *Use only selected features* box. Although this works great for a few polygons I'm wondering if there is a better way of achieving my objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way for a batch approach would be to:

1. Use the Point Sampling Tool plugin to add an attribute from the polygon layer to the point layer. That could be the state name. So now your points has an attribute listing the state the point is in.
2. Use the menu Vector > Data Management Tool > Split vector layer, where
   the input vector layer is your point layer and Unique ID field is the state name.

Comment: @Jakob- Sorry for the late response but thank you so much for your answer. This is just what I was looking for, especially 2.